# SQL Query Statistics Taking more time/physical reads in production

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Recently we have upgraded over application version in our prodution environment. Ever since the performance of our system became very slow. A Business usecase which used to complete within 1 hour in previous version is taking more than 3 hours to compelete in the current version. We analysed furthur and narrowed our problem to a single sql query. There is no change made either in the code corresposing to this query or the query itself. The number of times this query has executed in current version is almost the same as number of times the query has executed in previous version too and also we donot suspect too much change in database data as well. Our customer took statspack analysis for both version and found that this particular query is listed as the top query consuming more physical reads, more buffer gets, more elapsed time and more cpu time in current version whereas the statspack file correspoding to previous version does not even list this in even one catagory. 

So what are all the possiblities for the same query under almost same data load to result in more physical reads, more buffer gets, more elapsed time and more cpu time?

Comment: what application was upgraded? was it the Oracle Instance?

Comment: Actaully no software is upgraded. It is only application code changes. But changes does not pertain to the query which i have talked about.

Answer (score 0):

Such issues are mostly alluded to lack of or stale stats. Try collecting stats on the table.
Check if the any secondary indexes on the table was dropped recently. Also compare the explain plan of the query when it had a normal run versus the one that comsumes High IO/CPU.

Comment: Customer ha collected statspack file for more than five days and all have showed this query to be the crook. So i donot think we have stale stats. There were no change in any indexes as well. Concerning explain plan, we donot have the explain plan output of the this query for previous version. All current executions of this query(around 7K executions per day) are consuming more cputime/gets/physical reads.

Comment: @thiyaga - stats may still be stale if collection has been disabled; you can check the `last_analyzed` date in `all_tables` and `all_indexes`. Also maybe check if there are histograms that are throwing things off. Does the current plan use the indexes you expect?